# java.lang.NumberFormatException error in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, machine-learning, k-means, apache-spark-mllib

i am new to spark and machine learning, so to practice i was trying to write a k-means algorithm in spark 1.6.0 using a dataset.
i was doing as specified in example on apache spark website.
while doing so i got this error :

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af,33.6894754264,-1
>   17.543308253"

my code in which i got this error:

```
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("/user/rohitchopra32_gmail/Project2_Dataset")
rdd: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String] = MapPartitionsRDD[1] at textFile at <console>:28
scala> rdd.count()
res0: Long = 459540                                                             
scala> val parsedData = rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))).cache()
parsedData: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.Vector] = MapPartitionsRDD[2] at map at <console>:30

scala> parsedData.count()
17/08/21 16:22:50 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 10, ip-
172-31-58-214.ec2.internal): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af,33.6894754264,-1
17.543308253"
```

full traceback:

```
scala> parsedData.count()
17/08/21 16:22:50 ERROR TaskSetManager: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times; aborting job
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 0 in stage 2.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 0.3 in stage 2.0 (TID 10, ip-
172-31-58-214.ec2.internal): java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af,33.6894754264,-1
17.543308253"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Driver stacktrace:
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.org$apache$spark$scheduler$DAGScheduler$$failJobAndIndependentStages(DAGScheduler.scala:1431)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1419)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$abortStage$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ResizableArray$class.foreach(ResizableArray.scala:59)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayBuffer.foreach(ArrayBuffer.scala:47)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.abortStage(DAGScheduler.scala:1418)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler$$anonfun$handleTaskSetFailed$1.apply(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at scala.Option.foreach(Option.scala:236)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.handleTaskSetFailed(DAGScheduler.scala:799)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.doOnReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1640)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1599)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGSchedulerEventProcessLoop.onReceive(DAGScheduler.scala:1588)
        at org.apache.spark.util.EventLoop$$anon$1.run(EventLoop.scala:48)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:620)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1832)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1845)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1858)
        at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:1929)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.count(RDD.scala:1143)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:33)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:38)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:40)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:42)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:44)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:46)
        at $iwC$$iwC.<init>(<console>:48)
        at $iwC.<init>(<console>:50)
        at <init>(<console>:52)
at .<init>(<console>:56)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at .<init>(<console>:7)
        at .<clinit>(<console>)
        at $print(<console>)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$ReadEvalPrint.call(SparkIMain.scala:1065)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain$Request.loadAndRun(SparkIMain.scala:1346)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.loadAndRunReq$1(SparkIMain.scala:840)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:871)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkIMain.interpret(SparkIMain.scala:819)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.reallyInterpret$1(SparkILoop.scala:857)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.interpretStartingWith(SparkILoop.scala:902)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.command(SparkILoop.scala:814)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.processLine$1(SparkILoop.scala:657)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.innerLoop$1(SparkILoop.scala:665)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$loop(SparkILoop.scala:670)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply$mcZ$sp(SparkILoop.scala:997)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process$1.apply(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at scala.tools.nsc.util.ScalaClassLoader$.savingContextLoader(ScalaClassLoader.scala:135)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.org$apache$spark$repl$SparkILoop$$process(SparkILoop.scala:945)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.SparkILoop.process(SparkILoop.scala:1059)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main$.main(Main.scala:31)
        at org.apache.spark.repl.Main.main(Main.scala)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:731)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:181)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:206)
 at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:121)
        at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)
Caused by: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af,33.6894754264,-117.543308253"
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:2043)
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.parseDouble(FloatingDecimal.java:110)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:538)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at $iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:30)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at org.apache.spark.storage.MemoryStore.unrollSafely(MemoryStore.scala:283)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.putInBlockManager(CacheManager.scala:171)
        at org.apache.spark.CacheManager.getOrCompute(CacheManager.scala:78)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:268)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:66)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

here is the link for data set: [dataset](https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BwTgYzZKuzAZTVBXNnl2S0pkT3M)

help me guys fix this error.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You are splitting with space but your data looks like a CSV separated by coma

Comment: What are you trying to do? The expression `s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))` splits each line by spaces and tries to convert all the resulting elements to doubles. This doesn't match with your input date that is comma separated and contains all kinds of datatypes: 
`"2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af,33.6894754264,-1 17.543308253"`

Answer (score 0):

Referring to your input data

```
2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-b500-28f2342679af,33.6894754264,-1 17.543308253
```

You are trying to get the double value (`17.543308253`), convert it to `double` and use it for `Vectors.dense` for machine learning.

If thats the case then you should be doing

```
val parsedData = rdd.map(s => Vectors.dense(s.split(' ')(1).toDouble)).cache()
```

If you do `Vectors.dense(s.split(' ').map(_.toDouble))`, you are trying to convert the `2014-03-15:10:10:20,Sorrento,8cc3b47e-bd01-4482-500-28f2342679af,33.6894754264,-1` of your data to `double` too, which would give you `NumberFormatException`

I hope the answer is helpful